# How to display image from storage to cardview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i Was try to display image to card view but it not working and do not show error. Anyone help me please. I am new android. i checked file exists from downloaded folder: /storage/emulated/0/hismart/hinhmon

```
public class Album {
private String name;
private String gia;
private String thumbnail;
private String url;

public Album() {
}

public Album(String name, String gias, String thumbnail, String url) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gia = gias;
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGia() {
    return gia;
}

public void setGia(String gia) {
    this.gia = gia;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}


public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

}
```

Creat and add data to ArrayList:

```
List<String> ArrTenmon = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ArrGia = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ArrImgLocal = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ArrImgUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add

```
    }  Cursor c = db.getdata("select * from tbl_mon_app");
    int count = c.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        new DownloadFile().execute(ArrImgUrl.get(i));
        if (!fileloc.exists()) {
            fileloc.mkdirs();
        }

        Album a = new Album(ArrTenmon.get(i), ArrGia.get(i), ArrImgLocal.get(i), ArrImgUrl.get(i));
        albumList.add(a);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in adapter:

```
String folder_main = "hismart/hinhmon";
File fileloc = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

    }
}


public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.albumList = albumList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Album album = albumList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(album.getName());
    holder.count.setText(album.getGia() + " vnđ");

  File imgFile = new File(fileloc+"/"+ "album" + position);

  Glide.with(mContext).load(imgFile).into(holder.thumbnail);

}

 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albumList.size();
}
```

And Problem in bellow can not display image, name of image is: album1, alubm2...

```
File imgFile = new File(fileloc+"/"+ "album" + position);

Glide.with(mContext).load(imgFile).into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Download file:

```
 class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BookActivity.this);// Change Mainactivity.this with your activity name.
    String strFolderName;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        String targetFileName = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL((String) aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            targetFileName = aurl[0].substring(aurl[0].lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hismart/hinhmon/";
            File folder = new File(PATH);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();//If there is no folder it will be created.
            }
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PATH + targetFileName);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return targetFileName;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        if (mProgressDialog.getProgress() == mProgressDialog.getMax()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



    }
}
```

call asyntask to download file

```
 Cursor c = db.getdata("select * from tbl_mon_app");
    int count = c.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        new DownloadFile().execute(ArrImgLocal.get(i));
        if (!fileloc.exists()) {
            fileloc.mkdirs();
        }

    }
```

Logcat: Show nothing error

Result like this:[image after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd9hN.png)

Comment: post full code of image file saving

Comment: debug and check your getting file or not, there is no problem in Glide code

Comment: @Munir i was updated code of download file.

Comment: @rajahsekar     i checked file in folder. Download success.

Comment: Are you getting any error message in logcat

Comment: @rajahsekar     Logcat show nothing error do u wana view it?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Glide code which you used will works, i have used it many project. There might be problem in your image file. Cross check all the points Sd card permissions, file path use are getting correct

if not worked try to convert file to Uri, it may help

```
    File imgFile = new File(fileloc+"/"+ "album" + position);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imgView);
```

Comment: thank for help, i have try this code before but it still nothing changed. :(